# How do I add a few places in my demo tenant?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following code to list all the rooms defined in my demo tenant:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var room = await graphClient.Places
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Currently, I see no response as there are no results on running this query.

[image]

How do I add a few places in my demo tenant so that this query returns some results?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/place?view=graph-rest-1.0#see-also) places API doesn't support adding new places.

Only administrator of your tenant can create room list and room via the Exchange PowerShell cmdlets.

To create a room list, use cmdlet `New-DistributionGroup`.

To add a room to a room list, use cmdlet `Add-DistributionGroupMember`.

Resources:

[Configure room](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/calendaring/configure-room-finder-rooms-workspaces)

[New-DistributionGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps&preserve-view=true)

[Add-DistributionGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps&preserve-view=true)